# What word is better to use in the article - sex or gender?

Tags: word-choice

what is better to use in the scientific article - sex or gender? I am describing the findings of a poll and I am concerned about which word is more suitable to be used?

Comment: It's better to use the appropriate word depending on the context. Since we don't know the content of the scientific article, it's not possible for us to make that judgment.

Comment: I describe the demographic points of my sample: age, place of residence and sex (or gender??)

Answer (score 1):

If this question had been asked half a century ago, the answer would have been obvious: *sex*. At that time, nobody would have thought of using *gender* in any sense other than the one it has in grammar. Feminist literature then introduced *gender* as a technical term, with the meaning that was, in that theoretical context, different from the established meaning of *sex* , even though related to it. The next step in the development of the usage of that word was that many people picked up that usage of *gender*, without paying full attention to its theoretical underpinnings, and started using it as a straightforward synonym for the traditional meaning of *sex*. Presumably, what motivated the widespread use of *gender* in that sense is that it made it possible to talk about being male or female, without triggering associations with the sense that *sex* has in constructions such as *to have sex*.

If one is writing in a field in which *gender* is used in  the precise, technical sense, which is different from the relevant sense of *sex*, then, of course, the choice between the two terms will affect the precise meaning that one's words will convey, and should depend on what one intends to say.

On the other hand, in a context in which it is obvious that the theoretical distinction between sex and gender is not relevant to what one is trying to say (i.e. in a context in which, if one uses *gender*, one will be using it casually, in its everyday sense), the choice will be just a matter of style. The current trends seem to favour *gender*, but using *sex* for this purpose is still very far from being obsolete.

Generally, when writing a scientific or a scholarly article, it is wiser to base such terminological decisions on carefully observing how the relevant words are used in the recent literature in the same field, than on what somebody may post on a site like this one.

Comment: Just to add that, for trans people and people with issues relating to their gender identity, the distinction between sex and gender is not theoretical, it is real. Unless your poll concerns sexual intercourse or genitals, the concept relevant to the poll is presumably *gender*, not sex.